# SQL: find percentiles

Tags: sql

I have a table that has a certain numeric column called `Score`. I would like to execute a query on that table, whose result will have 100 rows, each representing the score corresponding with that percentile. For example, a result may look as follows:

```
 Percentile | Score
---------------------
 01         | 10
 02         | 12
 03         | 12
 04         | 17
 ...        | ...
 99         | 1684
 100        | 1685
```

The Score values in the result table above are actual score values that exist in the original table, and are not interpolated. An interpolated result will be better but is not a requirement.

There may be several heuristics that can produce such a result. What I'm using today (in code) is basically as follows - The Score value corresponding with a percentile will be the score value for which: the number of rows with smaller scores, divided by the total number of rows, rounded to an integer, equals to the percentile (I hope that's clear)

I can consider other heuristics if they are easier to implement

I'm working in MS-SQL, but would appreciate a solution that also works on MySQL.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's best to implement this within SQL itself.

Comment: @Dav: I'm not sure either. I'm trying to understand whether it's possible in SQL, and what are the performance implications. With tens of millions of records that I don't maintain in memory - maybe SQL is the best way.

Comment: @Dav: another point - if you think that it's not suitable for SQL, and you can back that up using concrete arguments, that's a valid **answer** is my opinion.

Comment: Eh, it's late, and to be honest I'm not an expert on things like stored procedures and whatnot - so it's quite possible that there's a decent way to do it in SQL that might be better performance-wise than alternatives. I'll let others who are more knowledgeable than I weigh in on that. It just struck me as a little more computationally complex than something I'd normally consider for a DB query.

Comment: And Quassnoi jumps in with a wonderful case in point. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `SQL Server`:

```
SELECT  percentile, score
FROM    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY percentile ORDER BY score) AS rn, percentile, score
        FROM    (
                SELECT  score, NTILE(100) OVER (ORDER BY score) AS percentile
                FROM    mytable
                ) q
        ) q2
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: Can this be used in any similar way on a SQL2000 server?  Mine is only 8.0.2055, so doesn't recognise ROW_NUMBER() or NTILE() for starters.